# How do I extract a list of lists from a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a DataFrame in Pandas:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
d = {'Person': ["A", "B", "B", "C"], 'Movies': ["ET", "Apollo 13", "12 Angry Men", "Citizen Kane"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print df
```

I'd like to extract from this DataFrame a list of lists containing one list for each person, and which contains all the movies that they watched. Something like:

```
[["ET"], ["Apollo 13", "12 Angry Men"], ["Citizen Kane"]]
```

This is probably straightforward but I'm struggling with it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
print(df.groupby("Person").agg(list)["Movies"].to_list())
```

Prints:

```py
[['ET'], ['Apollo 13', '12 Angry Men'], ['Citizen Kane']]
```